# Why oncollisionenter2d not working in vs code c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

Why is oncollisionenter2d method not working in vs code  and my  intellisence is working properly and only this method and ontriggerenter2d are not working

I want a solution for this

Comment: you need colliders, that are not triggers, and at least one rigidbody

Comment: The code i compiled and executed by Unity ... which IDE you use doesn't really matter at all

Comment: Can you share the code and the settings on the game objects you are trying to collide?

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine, but check if the two objects aren't a trigger and at least one has a rigidbody.
If the problem is that Visual Studio doesn't recognise that metod and gives you an error try to use the auto-compiling function of Visual Studio(changing only a few words: for example if you wrote 'OnCollisionStay2D' and then you want to change it in 'OnCollisionEnter2D' manually by changing just the word 'Stay' by replacing it with 'Enter' can may cause some errors.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried my best, I hope it's better.